# Xilinx FFT v8.0 core example testbench

Tags: fft, xilinx

I am trying to compute the DFT transform of a series of 16-bit input values using the Xilinx FFTv8.0 core on a Virtex 7 but I have some troubles understanding the datasheet.

More specifically, I am using a standard auto-generated testbench (see below) but the output is always zero. Even after being through the datasheet and the "Jim Wu's FPGA Blog" (http://myfpgablog.blogspot.de/2010/07/fft-results-from-matlab-fft-bit.html) many times, I still don't understand how to use it. I think I am confused by the multiple input/output of the core..

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer:
//
// Create Date:   14:25:20 05/14/2015
// Design Name:   fft_core
// Module Name:   C:/Users/Alberto/Documents/MEGA/Master II/Master Thesis/test_fft/fft_tb.v
// Project Name:  test_fft
// Target Device:  
// Tool versions:  
// Description: 
//
// Verilog Test Fixture created by ISE for module: fft_core
//
// Dependencies:
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module fft_tb;

    // Inputs
    reg aclk;
    reg s_axis_config_tvalid;
    reg s_axis_data_tvalid;
    reg s_axis_data_tlast;
    reg m_axis_data_tready;
    reg [7:0] s_axis_config_tdata;
    reg [31:0] s_axis_data_tdata;

    // Outputs
    wire s_axis_config_tready;
    wire s_axis_data_tready;
    wire m_axis_data_tvalid;
    wire m_axis_data_tlast;
    wire event_frame_started;
    wire event_tlast_unexpected;
    wire event_tlast_missing;
    wire event_status_channel_halt;
    wire event_data_in_channel_halt;
    wire event_data_out_channel_halt;
    wire [31:0] m_axis_data_tdata;

    // generate clk
    always #5 aclk =! aclk;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    fft_core uut (
        .aclk(aclk), 
        .s_axis_config_tvalid(s_axis_config_tvalid), 
        .s_axis_data_tvalid(s_axis_data_tvalid), 
        .s_axis_data_tlast(s_axis_data_tlast), 
        .m_axis_data_tready(m_axis_data_tready), 
        .s_axis_config_tready(s_axis_config_tready), 
        .s_axis_data_tready(s_axis_data_tready), 
        .m_axis_data_tvalid(m_axis_data_tvalid), 
        .m_axis_data_tlast(m_axis_data_tlast), 
        .event_frame_started(event_frame_started), 
        .event_tlast_unexpected(event_tlast_unexpected), 
        .event_tlast_missing(event_tlast_missing), 
        .event_status_channel_halt(event_status_channel_halt), 
        .event_data_in_channel_halt(event_data_in_channel_halt), 
        .event_data_out_channel_halt(event_data_out_channel_halt), 
        .s_axis_config_tdata(s_axis_config_tdata), 
        .s_axis_data_tdata(s_axis_data_tdata), 
        .m_axis_data_tdata(m_axis_data_tdata)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        aclk = 0;
        s_axis_config_tvalid = 0;
        s_axis_data_tvalid = 0;
        s_axis_data_tlast = 0;
        m_axis_data_tready = 0;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 0;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #150;

        s_axis_config_tvalid = 1;
        s_axis_data_tvalid = 1;
        //s_axis_data_tlast = 1;
        m_axis_data_tready = 1;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 1;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 1;

        // Add stimulus here

        // Some random inputs (just to understand how it works):
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001; // FFT desired (and not IFFT)
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00005678; // I have a real input signal, so the upper half (corresponding to the immaginary part) is zero
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001121;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001516;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001920;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001121;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001516;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001920;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001121;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001516;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001920;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001121;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001516;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001920;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001121;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001516;
        #10;
        s_axis_config_tdata = 8'b00000001;
        s_axis_data_tdata = 32'h00001920;
        #10;


    end

endmodule
```

Here are some screenshots of the waveform and of the core configuration I used (I don't have yet the authority to post it directly):
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ejccc4dm6zdw7h/FFT.zip?dl=0

Does anybody have an explanation or a working testbench (possibly written in Verilog) processing data with this ip core ?

I thank you in advance

### Edit:

For posteriority, the full code is available [here](https://github.com/asonnino/fourier-transmitter); details and explanations can be found in the [paper](https://sonnino.com/papers/figuli2016variable.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I kind of solved my problem. The core has huge latency before delivering data (several us).
So if someone else has the same problem, don't hesitate to dramatically increase the simulation time, it may solve your problem.